# Plot not working while sourcing the script

Tags: r, rstudio, r-caret

When I run the whole file with clicking Source in RStudio, I don't get plots for variant importance generated by caret. Normal plotting of points seem to work.

What is strange - running just that line seems to work fine.
Code to reproduce below:

```
library(caret)

data("PlantGrowth")
PlantGrowth$test1 <- sample(1:2, 30, replace=TRUE)
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)
model <- train(group ~ ., data=PlantGrowth, method="lvq", preProcess="scale",
               trControl=control)
# estimate variable importance
importance <- varImp(model, scale=FALSE)
# summarize importance
print(importance)
# plot importance
plot(4, 5)
plot(importance)
plot(2, 3)
```

Two point-plots appear normally, but importance doesn't when sourcing the file. RStudio version: 1.1.453

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment, but can't add pictures there. Does your desired plot appear, when you go back one plot? See figure.

[image]

Comment: No, it doesn't. I just added the dummy plots before and after to show they are both plotted, but my real application only has the requested plot.